# ASPNETDB.MDF file cannot be opened in vs 2008 .The database cannot be opened because it is version 655

Tags: asp.net

i have  an application which is developed in vs  2003, and  i am using  DB ASPNETDB.MDF
now  i am trying to open the  same   project in vs 2008 it opens  when when i try to open the ASPNETDB.MDF  db which is  indide the App_data  it  give  me an error telling

ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

thank  you

Answer (score 1):

vs 2008 ships with SQL Server 2005 Express, which won't open your file.
I had the same issue. Please see product /versions mappings

SQL Server 7.0 ---- 515
SQL Server 2000 -- 539
SQL Server 2005 -- 611/612
SQL Server 2008 -- 655

Uninstalling SQL Server 2005 Express and installing SQL Server 2008 Express does the job. You can also try to export your data on a machine with 2008 installed to a sql file and import it in the 2005 version again.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that your file is a SQL Server Express 2005 database, and you do not have a compatible version on your new machine.

Either install SQL Server Express 2005, or transfer the data to a compatible database.